# Hiding the Survey List from browser in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

Every time I try to hide the Survey list from browser in Sharepoint Designer 2013 I receive an error telling me I couldn't. I am able to hide other kinds of list, besides that one.

[image]

Today, I have to run a script to hide it. I would like to do it using the Sharepoint Designer, instead.

Answer (score 0):

To hide it, you can just remove the Web Part that display this list. I hope this can help

Comment: It would still be accessible through Site Content though

Comment: In this case, we can modify the permissions of this list, that it can be viewed by only some users or groups

Comment: I want to hide the list from the tree menu, this checkbox does it. The permission wouldn't do it because I have to allow users to access the list, just not to see it in the menu.